# Potential energy curve for dissociation of cation of carbon dioxide

Tags: quantum-chemistry, spectroscopy

Can anyone suggest me some literature where I can find the potential energy curve or the electronic states for singly ionized $\ce{CO2}$ ($\ce{CO2+}$) dissociating into singly charged oxygen ($\ce{O+}$) and carbon monoxide ($\ce{CO}$).

Comment: Check out my edit, you can get more info: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here?r=SearchResults&s=24|10.4115 https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261/is-mathjax-in-titles-a-problem-and-why?r=SearchResults&s=21|12.8023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few of the literatures are here:
http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-4075/47/12/124025/meta

https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jp907351s

https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.444413